# If i were to develop a software for DBA's to help them in query optimization, what features could i incorporate?

Tags: sql-server-2008, optimization

What would be your expectations from such a software. I am planning to show the DBA a list of the top cpu and memory intensive queries along with the query plan, etc. How could i assist the DBA more to help him optimize his queries ? What kind of data does a DBA need to Optimize all queries on his server ?

I am working for the SQL SERVER right now.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect it to work as well as SQL Profiler. You and the DBA know that it's built into SSMS, right? Hell, some of the dynamic management views show you the big offenders without even needing to run Profiler.